# Integrating Token based security into existing Spring Security web application

Tags: spring, spring-security, restful-authentication

I am designing a RESTful web services that needs to be accessed by user after proper authentication. I have already developed Security for my application using Spring Security 3.0. Now I want to integrate TokenBasedAuthentication. But I stuck here for how do i do this.

**My ApplicationContextSecurity.xml:**

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    </global-method-security>
    <beans:bean id="myAccessDecisionManager"
        class="com.app.security.MyAccessDecisionManager">
    </beans:bean>
    <http auto-config="true" once-per-request="true"
        access-decision-manager-ref="myAccessDecisionManager"       
        access-denied-page="/jsp/errorPage.jsp">
        <intercept-url pattern="/*.app" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.app"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/login/checking.app"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.app?login_error=1" />
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            logout-success-url="/login.app" invalidate-session="true" />
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.app"
            session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="100"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
        </session-management>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"></authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.app.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    </beans:bean>
```

**My CustomAuthenticationProvider :**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
private ILoginService loginService;

protected final transient Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePassswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            authentication.getPrincipal(), authentication.getCredentials());

    // Doing authentication process here and returning authentication token
    return usernamePassswordAuthenticationToken;
}

public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
}
```

My requirement is,

- When user want to access rest web service at first time he should provide userName/password to the server from header.
- Server will accept the request, check the authentication and generate token for future requests for specific period.
  Also I need client side code for how to access secured web services.
  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When user want to access rest web service at first time he should
>   provide userName/password to the server from header.
>
> Server will accept the request, check the authentication and generate
>   token for future requests for specific period

You can do this either using HTTP headers or a normal HTTP POST request mapped to a Spring MVC controller (this is how we do it in our apps):

```
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    AuthenticationManager     authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/authenticate")
    public @ResponseBody String authenticate(@RequestParam final String username, @RequestParam final String password, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        final Authentication authenticationResult = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationRequest);

        final String token = <some randomly generated secure token>;

        final Authentication authentication = new MyAuthenticationToken(authenticationResult, token);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        this.securityContextRepository.saveContext(SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), request, response);

        return token;
    }
}
```

Once this is done, the client should send the token in an HTTP header with every subsequent request.

> Also I need client side code for how to access secured web services

Not sure what exactly you are looking for here.  If your client is a JavaScript library running in a web browser, setting the authentication token as an HTTP header with every request should be straightforward.  If your client is a device, the device could store the token in memory and include it as an HTTP header with every request using whatever HTTP client library you are using to invoke the services.