# Spring security not working while upgrading spring security 3.0 to spring security 3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I had successfully integrated spring security 3.0 in web application and it was running well, now I am going to upgrade spring security 3.0 to 3.1 and I am facing problem at my CustomAuthenticationManager
Whenever I try to login, CustomAuthenticationManager get called twice. So at first time user authenticate successfully and return usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken but this class get called again and this time principal returns proper value but credentials return null hence user get authentication failure and redirect to login page again and that's why I can't login ever.

**CustomAuthenticationManger:**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    private ILoginService loginService;
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePassswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authentication.getPrincipal(), authentication.getCredentials());
        if (loginService.authenticateUser((String) authentication.getPrincipal())) {
            if (loginService.validateUserIdAndPass((String) authentication.getPrincipal(), (String) authentication.getCredentials())) {
                usernamePassswordAuthenticationToken.setAuthenticated(false);
            } else
                throw new BadCredentialsException(
                        "Username/Password does not match");
        } else
            throw new BadCredentialsException(
                    "Username/Password does not match");
        return usernamePassswordAuthenticationToken;
    }
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

**My ApplicationContextSecurity.xml:**

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">     
    </global-method-security>  
    <beans:bean id="myAccessDecisionManager"
        class="com.app.common.security.repository.MyAccessDecisionManager"> 
    </beans:bean> 

    <http auto-config="true" once-per-request="true"
        access-decision-manager-ref="myAccessDecisionManager" access-denied-page="/jsp/errorPage.jsp">

        <intercept-url pattern="/*.app"  access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>  

         <form-login login-page="/login.app" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            default-target-url="/login/validate.app"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.app?login_error=1" />
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            logout-success-url="/login.app" invalidate-session="true" /> 
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.app"
            session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="100"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
        </session-management>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"></authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.app.common.security.repository.CustomAuthenticationProvider">        
    </beans:bean>
```

please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: I recommend to us a Debugger to analyse it. (or throw an exception in your CustomAuthenticationProvider and analyse the stacktrace)

Comment: @Ralph I am not getting what you want to say, because as I mentioned above at first time a function authenticate() works properly but I don't know why this function again get called and that time an instance authentication contain null value for credentials and that's why it throw BadCredentialsException exception. I just want to know how to prevent or why my authenticate() function getting called twice?

Comment: What I want to say is: have a look at the code that invokes your method, and then try to understand why it does so. -- A Debugger or an Exception is just a way to find the way in which the method is invoked.

Comment: @Ralph I did as you said above but I can't understand what's going on because when I change spring security jars to 3.0 then it works well but when I change it to 3.1 it start to work as mentioned above. I am just changing jars as spring-security-acl-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-security-config-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-security-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-security-ldap-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-security-taglibs-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: Is this the configuration as used by you? You are configuring the default `authentication-manager` but reference a different one with the `access-decision-manager-ref` attribute.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, customAuthenticationManager is used to authenticate user and then check for authorization for request url is done in myAccessDecisionManager that's it.

Comment: Sorry may bad, I read authentication-manager-ref... (I need to get new glasses I guess :) ). However isn't your implemention in your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` wrong? After validation you should be authenticated, however you set it to `false` instead of `true`. When set to `false` re-authentication (when needed) is requested.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your replay, I set it true as you mentioned but still it execute twice and at second time credentials become null and it throws BadCredentialsException. I cant understand why this code works with spring security 3.0, with this version also method get called twice but name and password remains same and I can login successfully.

Comment: What is so special about your authentication that you need a custom `AuthenticationProvider`? I don't see anything special (unless that is done inside your `ILoginService` implementation.

Comment: @M.Deinum In CunstoAuthenticationManager I am just comparing userId and password from database and this done by using ILoginService. Actually as I set true as you said it gives an error as "Cannot set this token to trusted - use constructor which takes a GrantedAuthority list instead". so any suggestion?

Comment: Why not use the default implementation from Spring Security? That is already provided out-of-the-box? However we still have the issue of the double invocation which shouldn't happen.

Comment: One other thing, why are there no `GrantedAuthority` instances being set? You now basically have created a login, without any rights.

Comment: @M.Deinum In my application the process of accessing any resource is divided into two parts first: to check whether user is authenticate or not by using CustomAuthenticationManager second: after successful authentication we check that request url is accessible to that user or not in MyAccessDessionManager

Comment: Ok. Still the fact that authentication is triggered twice is already wrong, it should only be triggered once. So basically that is the error. I suggest you enable TRACE/DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.security` and see what happens. Then add the output to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum As I saw DEBUG log I understand the issue, in my security context file I specified default-target as "/login/validate.app" so after successful authentication on first time it goes to login controller at validate.app, here I am just getting the userInfo as: userId, userPassword, etc, by using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(). But it returns null for credentials, then this method returns as return "redirect:/userHome.app"; and that's why authentication called again but this time it gets failed due to null credentials now how to solve it, please help me.

Comment: Can you add the code for the Controller...

Comment: @M.Deinum actually I solved my problem just adding attribute erase-credentials="false" in authentication-manager tag. But I got this solution only because of your suggestions. Thanks, thanks a lot.

Comment: Well that isn't a solution but merely a workaround IMHO. The real problem is is that the authentication is invoked twice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38006/discussion-between-balasaheb-and-m-deinum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Spring 3.0.3 (and later) the default `AuthenticationManager` the `ProviderManager` clears the credentials after an authetnication attempt ([SEC-1493](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1493)). You must have been an on older version (pre 3.0.3 of Spring Security).

Your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` is also flawed as you should set authenticated to `true` after a succesful authentication (else interceptors extending `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` will re-attempt authentication.

Links

1. [SEC-1493](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1493)
2. ProviderManager [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/db913f685715f04b1a477a33fb4d76f21b819099)
3. AbstractSecurityInterceptor [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/AbstractSecurityInterceptor.html)

Comment: Hi could you please give me suggestion for my old post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827500/integrating-token-based-security-into-existing-spring-security-web-application?rq=1)